# How to download an entire folder/directory from a website in java

Tags: java, android, download, file-handling

I have a site that can generate questionnaires to my survey app in android.. all the questionnaires goes to a single folder. Is there a way to download all the questionnaires without knowing every single address of the questionnaires? 
I already know how to download a single file, but I want to download an entire folder/directory form a website using java

from    private static String file_url = "http://umsurvey.comlu.com/admin/question/";

to       OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Question/");

Comment: This is not possible, unless you know all the URLs to all of the contents of the "entire folder/directory". Also, **NEVER HARDCODE PATHS** in Android development (e.g., `/sdcard`), as it will be wrong in many cases.

Comment: yes it is just a sample i use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ofcourse..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. but you can generate a text file from your php that  every-time you generate a questionnaires the file name of the questionnaire will add to the text-file.

Comment: can you send me a sample code sir?

Comment: sure. I will email it to you.. what's your email ad?